# Event associated to push notification is not triggered on android

Tags: genexus, genexus-sd

I have a Menu main object with this code for the notification:

```
Event 'notiopenpet'
    &Msg = format( !'*** notiopenpet %1', &Value)
    msg( &Msg, status)
EndEvent
```

And this the server side notification code:

```
&NotificationConfiguration.ApplicationId = !'...'
&Notification.Actions.DefaultAction.Event.Name = !"notiopenpet"
&Notification.Actions.DefaultAction.Event.Parameters.FromJson( format( !'[{"Name":"Value","Value":"%1"}]', !'123'))
&Notification.Appearance.Icon.Large = !'https://...'
&Notification.Appearance.Icon.Small = !'icon_...'
&NotificationDelivery.Expiration = 3000 
&NotificationDelivery.Priority   = PushNotificationPriority.Normal


GeneXus.Common.Notifications.SendNotification(
    &NotificationConfiguration,
    &SDTDeviceInfo.DeviceToken,
    &Notification, 
    &NotificationDelivery, 
    &OutMessages,
    &IsSuccessful
)
```

It's works fine in iOS but in Android, the push notification arrives ok but when I tap it, the app is open but the event is not triggered.

GeneXus 18
Version: 18.0.169539 U2